# How to block/bulk reset static variables using Java 7

Tags: java, static

I am parsing a text file looking for syntax matches. to complete this task, I created Variable class with static variables in it. Then I parse a file and  I assign the parsed information to the variable class static elements.

```
Variable.name = "the parsed information";
```

Then I created a Baseline class to check and compare against the Variable elements to check if certain condition is met.

For example

```
if (BaseLine.x.equal(Variable.x) // do whatever.
```

Variable Class:

```
public class Variable {
    static String name; 
    static String userID;
    static Integer age
}
```

BaseLine Class:

```
public class BaseLine {
        static String name; 
        static String userID;
        static Integer age
    }
```

Utilizing JavaFX I move between scenes to load a file, parse it, assign the parsed variable then compare it with my BaseLine class. Thus far, Everything works as expected until I hit the back button to go back to the original scene to load a new file. now, the issue that I am having how can I reset the variable inside my Variable class in bulk instead of doing it one by one inside my controller initialize statement? I want to do this to ensure that I don't capture any variable from the older file I just parsed before I hit the back button. what is the correct way of completing this task?

I was able to get what I am looking for when I reset the variables inside my initialize controller, but it seems to be a lengthy process to do for OOP I have over 100 variables (int/sets/strings...) to reset.

Here is what I did to reset the static Variables inside the controller initialize section.

```
 @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

            Variable.name = null;
            Variable.setName.clear();
            Variable.age = null;
```

Comment: avoid static states. it's untestable, and a consequence of a bad oo design

Comment: Sounds like a poor plan. I'd bet you're better off having instance variables instead of static ones. Instantiate a new instance of the object rather than resetting static variables.

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to get what I am looking for when I reset the variables inside my initialize controller, but it seems to be a lengthy process to do for OOP I have over 100 variables (int/sets/strings...) to reset.

If you have hundreds of static variables, you are not doing OOP properly.  In proper OO design, your application's state should be held in instance variables, and accessed via instance variables.  Static variables should be kept to an absolute minimum.  (You can eliminate them entirely, if you can use a dependency injection (DI) framework ...)

The bad news is that there is no >>good<< way to reset a large number of
static variables.  There are a couple of >>bad<< ways; e.g. reflection, and messing around with classloaders ... but you just would be replacing one problem (clunky code) with a worse one (complex, fragile code).  IMO.

But the good news is that you fix your design / implementation to be properly OO, then you won't have this nasty problem of resetting the variables.  And a whole bunch of other things will be easier too ... like writing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way that would exists that would allow you to reset all static variables in one go. You would have to do one by one.

I think your problem lies somewhere else - and i believe you should refactor your code in that instance (if possible).

How about having all your variables as standard (non static) and set/get them like you normally would but when done just create new object and let the old one be collected by Garbage collector??

**Edit:**

Although you could perhaps use reflection ? Not entirely sure if that would work though.

Something like

```
Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers() && isRightName(field.getName()) {
        field = null;
    } 
}
```